# Proof in Circle geometry question

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle

> Let Γ be a semicircle with diameter . The point  lies on the diameter  and points  and  lie on the arc , with  between  and . Let the tangents to Γ at  and  meet at . Suppose that ∠ = ∠. Prove that ∠ = ∠ + ∠.

I got this question from a sample competition paper aimed at 16-18 year olds.
I think that I can prove this by proving that the point C must be at the circle's centre by contradiction; if it wasn't then the 2 angles which are supposedly equal wouldn't in fact be equal.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is my argument correct?
2. If my argument is correct, what would be a rigorous proof for my argument?
3. Is there an alternative method? If so please hint to it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly not the case that $C$ must be the center. Consider the diagram below:

[image]

Here $C$ is not the center. However $\angle EFD = \angle ACD + \angle ECB$ still holds.

To show that equality, it suffices to show that $CEFD$ is cyclic.

This can be accomplished by proving the orange angles below are equal, and that is my hint. (There could be alternative methods but I'm not sure)

[image]

We will need to show that $CE = CG$ given that $\angle ECB = \angle GCB$.

Consider the center of the circle, $O$. $OE = OG$ as radii, with $OC$ as common sides, leads to $\triangle COE \cong \triangle COG$ by "long side-short side-angle".

We can also see this by dropping perpendiculars from $O$. Then $\triangle COP \cong \triangle COP'$ by AAS, and $\triangle POE \cong \triangle P'OE$ by RHS. Either way, we have $CE = EG$, and we can proceed.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake stemmed from a poorly drawn diagram that led me to make assumptions. I'm not certain about how to prove the required fact you stated; would you mind posting a full solution?

Comment: I could prove it another way if I could prove that the midpoint of EG is on the diameter and EG is perpendicular to the diameter, but I can;t see a way to do that either.

Comment: Then we just need to show that $\triangle CEG$ is isosceles.